# If a column is NO, change another column to Closed

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a SharePoint list with a status column which has the following in which works great. I'm looking to add to the formula dependent on another column - is this possible?

If consent required column is No then the status changes to Closed.

Can anyone tell me what to add please?

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Confirmed Receipt Date]),"Open","Closed")
```

Comment: Do you want to add the condition in the existing formula? If Yes, what will be the relation for these two conditions? AND/OR/anything else? which condition should execute first? Also. what is the data type of your "consent required" column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the "consent required" column before "Confirmed Receipt Date" then use:

```
=IF([consent required]="No","Close",IF(ISBLANK([Confirmed Receipt Date]),"Open","Closed"))
```

**Note**: Use the correct **Display Name** of your "consent required" column.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF([YOUR COLUMN NAME]="No","Closed","Open")
```

If *your column* is Boolean(Yes/No):

```
=IF([YOUR COLUMN NAME]=FALSE,"Closed","Open")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested `AND` function:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK([Confirmed Receipt Date]), [ConsentRequired]=TRUE),"Open","Closed")
```